# Calling a thread within a module in python

Tags: python, multithreading, import, module

I have a log in screen which calls a module from a file which is 'HomescreenscrollCopy31' . This works perfectly fine.

The only issue is that there is a thread within the module which does not seem to operate.

Here is the code in the login screen:

```
def login():
    content = nameentry.get()
    content1 = IDentry.get()
    if content == "1" and content1 == "1":
        root.destroy()
        from HomescreenscrollCopy31 import FullScreenApp
```

The HomescreenscrollCopy31.py file looks like this,

```
class FullScreenApp(object):
     def __init__(self, master, **kwargs):
        self.master=master
        pad=3
        self._geom='200x200+0+0'
        master.geometry("{0}x{1}+0+0".format(
            master.winfo_screenwidth()-pad, master.winfo_screenheight()-pad))
        master.bind('<Escape>',self.toggle_geom)            
    def toggle_geom(self,event):
        geom=self.master.winfo_geometry()
        print(geom,self._geom)
        self.master.geometry(self._geom)
        self._geom=geom

    def trick(threadName, sleepTime):
        while 1 < 2:
            .....

    try:
        t = threading.Thread(target=trick, args=("Trick running", 5))
        t.daemon = True
        t.start()
    except: Exception,
    print "start up"
```

It seems that it runs through the HomescreenscrollCopy31.py and politely prints the "start up" only to tease me, as it never actually runs the thread and thus should print the "Trick running" output.

Why is this?

Comment: This is a very, very weird design. Why are you starting a thread as part of a class definition? And why define something as a method that will never actually be callable as a normal method? At least if you marked it `@staticmethod` it would be a bit more understandable…

Comment: Also, you've given us a whole mass of irrelevant code, but left out what may be the most important part. Does `trick` actually print `threadName` anywhere? Does it wait on some sync object before doing so? And so on. All of the most obvious things that could be wrong are within `trick`, and you haven't shown us any of that code. (And, as a side note, why would you write `while 1 < 2: ` instead of `while True:`?)

Comment: Is the indentation here actually right?  abarnert's right -- this is quite strange.  Also, the try-except block isn't right -- It should raise a `SyntaxError` I would think ...

Comment: try `target=self.trick`

Comment: I take that back, You are just importing without instantiating and then trying to access the class member which is a staticmethod?

Comment: Are you sure your program is not returning immediately after starting the new thread? if it is you should use thread.join() to be sure to wait for the thread to finish in your main thread.

Comment: Things I do not understand: "You are just importing without instantiating" @Ashwin "At least if you marked it staticmethod it would be a bit more understandable" abarnert "you should use thread.join()" user2706615. Despite the helpful advice, I still do not know where I am going wrong here!

Answer (score 0):

I think it's better to write it this way.

```
def login():
    content = nameentry.get()
    content1 = IDentry.get()
    if content == "1" and content1 == "1":
        root.destroy()
        from HomescreenscrollCopy31 import FullScreenApp
        myFullScreenApp = FullScreenApp(...)  # you need to give it some input, like master, to initialize an instance for FullScreenApp class




class FullScreenApp(object):

    def __init__(self, master, **kwargs):
        self.master=master
        pad=3
        self._geom='200x200+0+0'
        master.geometry("{0}x{1}+0+0".format(
            master.winfo_screenwidth()-pad, master.winfo_screenheight()-pad))
        master.bind('<Escape>',self.toggle_geom)   

        # these code will be executed when instance initializing 
        t = threading.Thread(target=self.trick, args=["Trick running", 5])
        t.daemon = True
        t.start()


    def toggle_geom(self,event):
        geom=self.master.winfo_geometry()
        print(geom,self._geom)
        self.master.geometry(self._geom)
        self._geom=geom

    def trick(threadName, sleepTime):
        while 1 < 2:
            .....
```

1. You just need to initialize an instance of the class to get thread
   running. If using staticmethod way, it will make code more
   complicated which I don't recommend.
2. When invoking a new thread, args should be a list([]) but not a
   tuple(()).
3. You can use while 1 instead of while 1<2. Anyway, this is not the
   major issue. :)

Hope it helps.